# Failure to plot a subset of curves using ParametricPlot

Tags: plotting, complex, parametric-functions

I wish to plot a parametric curve with parameters `Γ`,`Δ`,`ϵ` such that

```
Γ^4 Δ^2 + 16 (Δ^2 + ϵ^2)^3 + Γ^2 (8 Δ^4 - 20 Δ^2 ϵ^2 - ϵ^4) = 0
```

My attempt is of the following: I intend to plot a series of parametric curves with `ϵ` on the x-axis and `Δ` on the y-axis. So, my parameterization is such that `x = ϵ` and `y = Δ` with `Γ = 0.1`. As such, I will need to solve the equation above for `Δ` in terms of `ϵ` (`Γ` = 0.1). Reordering the equation above and grouping terms of `Δ`, we have that:

```
16 Δ^6 - Γ^2 ϵ^4 + 16 ϵ^6 + Δ^4 (8 Γ^2 + 48 ϵ^2) + Δ^2 (Γ^4 - 20 Γ^2 ϵ^2 + 48 ϵ^4) = 0
```

Where `Δ` is a polynomial of order 6. Defining the polynomial as

```
poly = 16 Δ^6 - Γ^2 ϵ^4 + 16 ϵ^6 + Δ^4 (8 Γ^2 + 48 ϵ^2) + Δ^2 (Γ^4 - 20 Γ^2 ϵ^2 + 48 ϵ^4)
```

and doing

```
Solve[poly == 0, Δ]
```

returns **six** solutions of `Δ` (I will not list the solutions here since it is really long but it can be checked in *Mathematica*). **Three** of which the solutions are simply the negative of the other **Three**. Without loss of generality, I name my solutions `Δ1p`, `Δ2p`, `Δ3p` where the `p` denotes the positive solutions and `Δ1n`, `Δ2n`, `Δ3n` denoting the negative solutions of the respective positive ones.

I proceed to do my parametric plot for all (six) solutions going from `ϵ = 0` to `ϵ = 0.05`:

```
ParametricPlot[{{ϵ, Δ1p}, {ϵ, Δ1n}, {ϵ, Δ2p}, {ϵ, Δ2n}, {ϵ, Δ3p}, {ϵ, Δ3n}}, {ϵ, 0, 0.05}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 10^4, Exclusions -> None]
```

and I was returned a plot like so
[image]

The problem here is that the green and red curves do not connect (they were predicted to be). Moreover, since there are 6 curves, there should be 6 curves of different color. But there are only 4 separate colors in this instance. I investigated further and decided to plot the 3rd solution (`Δ3p`):

```
ParametricPlot[{{ϵ, Δ3p}}, {ϵ, 0, 0.05}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 10^4, Exclusions -> None]
```

and was returned with a **blank** **graph** (and so by symmetry, plotting for `Δ3n` also returns a blank graph. This explains the missing two colors).  **Why is this happening?**, **what is special about `Δ3p`?**

Comment: `Δ3p` is not `Real`; you can  plot the real part using `ParametricPlot[
 Re@{\[Epsilon], \[CapitalDelta]3p}, {\[Epsilon], 0, 0.05}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 10^4, Exclusions -> None]`.

Comment: Why not use `ContourPlot[]`? `With[{Γ = 1/10}, ContourPlot[Γ^4 Δ^2 + 16 (Δ^2 + ϵ^2)^3 + Γ^2 (8 Δ^4 - 20 Δ^2 ϵ^2 - ϵ^4) == 0, {ϵ, 0, 3/100}, {Δ, -1/100, 1/100}, PlotPoints -> 95]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use exact numbers for `Γ` and add the option `WorkingPrecision -> 20` to `ParametricPlot`:

```
Γ = 1/10;
exp = Γ^4 Δ^2 +  16 (Δ^2 + ϵ^2)^3 + Γ^2 (8 Δ^4 -     20 Δ^2 ϵ^2 - ϵ^4);
{Δ1p, Δ2p, Δ3p, Δ1n, Δ2n, Δ3n} =  Δ /. Solve[exp == 0, Δ];
ParametricPlot[{{ϵ, Δ1p}, {ϵ,  Δ1n}, {ϵ, Δ2p}, {ϵ, Δ2n}, {ϵ, Δ3p}, {ϵ,     Δ3n}}, 
  {ϵ, 0, 0.05}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> "Expressions",
  PlotPoints -> 100, Exclusions -> None, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

[image]

Since the last four solutions have complex elements

```
FreeQ[_Complex] /@ {Δ1p, Δ2p,  Δ3p, Δ1n, Δ2n,  Δ3n}
```

> {True, True, False, False, False, False}

you can plot the real parts:

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{{ϵ, Re@Δ1p}, {ϵ,  Re@Δ1n}, {ϵ, Re@Δ2p}, {ϵ, Re@Δ2n}, 
 {ϵ, Re@Δ3p}, {ϵ, Re@Δ3n}}], {ϵ, 0, 0.05}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, Exclusions -> None, WorkingPrecision -> 20, 
 PlotLegends -> {"{ϵ, Re@Δ1p}", "{ϵ, Re@Δ1n}", "{ϵ, Re@Δ2p}", 
   "{ϵ, Re@Δ2n}", "{ϵ, Re@Δ3p}", "{ϵ, Re@Δ3n}"} ]
```

[image]

or the imaginary parts (replacing `Re` with `Im` above):

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is what I needed. A follow up question: You have only 4 colors in the first plot but the legends show 6. I again suspect it's `\[CapitalDelta]3p` and `\[CapitalDelta]3n` so I plotted them separately by commenting out the other 4 curves. I am returned with another blank plot. What is happening there?

Comment: @kowalski,  `Δ3p` and `Δ3n` are complex for all values of `ϵ` in the interval  `[0, 0.05]`; that's why they don't show up in the combined plot and you get an empty plot when you try to plot them separately.

Comment: @klgr Thanks! This has been helpful

Comment: @klgr Not sure if you will see this, but a quick follow up question: Why are the Real parts of the curve look different than the regular solutions/curves? If it is real, it should keep plotting it on the graph rather than stopping at the cusps (as shown in your plot for the Re parts). This has been troubling me terribly

Comment: @kowalski,  compare `Plot[x +I , {x, 0, 1}]` vs `Plot[Re[x + I], {x, 0, 1}]`.